# First page background color when exporting HTML to Word

Tags: html, css, .net, ms-word, export

When exporting HTML to a Word document, is it possible to have a different background color for specific pages? I want to create a document with a blue background on the first page, and on all the following pages 'just' a white background.

I export the HTML to Word by setting the content-type this way:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-word")
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Rapport.doc")
```

The HTML header:

```
ExportHeader &= "<html>"
ExportHeader &= "<head>"
ExportHeader &= "<style>"
ExportHeader &= "html,body,th,td { font-family:Verdana,Arial; font-size:9pt; }"
ExportHeader &= "body { background-color: #1c3f94; } "
ExportHeader &= "h3 { font-size:12pt; }"
ExportHeader &= "</style>"
ExportHeader &= "</head>"
ExportHeader &= "<body>"
```

In the body I add tables to align content the way I want.

```
ExportBody &= "<table>"
ExportBody &= "<tr><td>First blue background</td></tr>"
ExportBody &= "</table>"

ExportBody &= "<br clear=all style='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always' />"

ExportBody &= "<table>"
ExportBody &= "<tr><td>Second page, white background</td></tr>"
ExportBody &= "</table>"
```

The footer:

```
ExportFooter &= "</body>"
ExportFooter &= "</html>"
```

What I want to achieve:

[image: Example result]

Comment: In order to support a different background color a section break would be necessary, same as if different margins, page orientation or headers/footers were required. Best would probably be to create a document in Word with the desired settings, save it as HTML then look at the HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @CindyMeister. I did try that, but when I finally export the generated HTML back into a Word (.docx) document and open it in MS Word, it breaks the desired layout.

I ended up using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application() to merge some data into an existing .docs file. The first results looks promising. Have a nice day!

Comment: I just read that using Office.Interop in a server environment is **not recommended**. I'm going to use Open XML instead, it seems promising.